# Como funciona a desvinculação geral após entrar em um sistema utilizando Redes Sociais?

Tags: javascript, html, css, processo, integração

É comum a "entrada" de um usuário em sistemas atuais utilizando uma conta ja cadastrada em outra rede. Os mais comuns que vejo são facebook, google e etc..

O `processo` é simples e pode ser demonstrado da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse `momento` podemos pegar algumas informações deste usuário, como login, email, tokens, id entre outras informações fornecidas nesta integração. A partir dai podemos persistir o dado em nosso banco de dados, mas mesmo assim ficariamos dependente de um cadastro de senha para que o usuário acesse o sistema sem a integração de redes sociais.

Quando resolvemos o problema da senha de alguma maneira seja ela qual for, podemos dar origem a outro problema pois o usuário terá um acesso, porem com informações que podem ser retiradas do sistema pelo usuário. Pois suponhamos que:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o usuário quiser `desvincular` suas informações de rede utilizada para entrar no sistema.Qual seria a melhor abordagem para fazermos isso? Quais os cuidados que devemos ter, e quais as peculiaridades a se tomar cuidado ao fazer isso?

Resumidamente minha pergunta seria: Dado a muitas necessidades em integrar o acesso de usuarios utilizando redes sociais, quais cuidados devemos ter quando o usuario quiser desvincular suas informações obtidas nas redes sociais do sistema que a implantou-as.

Comment: Geralmente você retêm o e-mail, sendo assim a abordagem mais provavel é manter tudo, mas só desligar a parte da rede social pelo token, a senha continua funcionando, o email também e o nome de usuário também, só não poderá mais se logar via rede social. Eu não negativei, só pra avisar, mas a pergunta me parece off-topic, um bom lugar pra perguntar seria o chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha, mas de qualquer forma adiantei o que entendi e o que me parece razoavel, lembrando se optar só pelo token (sem senha) a pessoa poderia voltar o vinculo.

Answer (score 1):

Como você já disse, normalmente a informação que causa quebra nessa situação é a Senha, pois as demais teoricamente estão salvas no BD do seu sistema. A maioria dos sistemas não oferece nenhum informativo para o usuário após a desvinculação, fazendo com que o usuário tenha que deduzir o processo para "regularizar" sua conta, que normalmente é:

> Logout > Esqueci minha senha > Login

Esse é um erro de usabilidade que pode ser facilmente corrigido obrigando o usuário a informar uma nova senha para concluir a desvinculação.

Em relação aos dados coletados, creio que possa ser facilmente resolvido permitindo alterações na "página de perfil" de acordo com as suas regras de negócio. Normalmente essas informações podem ser alteradas mesmo com uma conta vinculada, pois o intuito é agilizar o processo de cadastro do usuário, e não as utilizar como "fonte de verdade".